# protobuf-net.Grpc Flow/Congestion Control

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, .net-6.0, protobuf-net.grpc

I'm working on a program which will asynchronously load large amounts of data from a server via gRPC (both ends use protobuf-net.Grpc).

While I can simply throw large amounts of data at the client via `IAsyncEnumerable`, I sometimes want to prioritize sending certain parts earlier (where the priorities are determined on the fly, and not know at the start, kind of like sending a video stream and skipping ahead).

If I were to send data and wait for a response every time I'd be leaving a lot of bandwidth unused. The alternative would be throwing tons of data at the client, which could cause network congestion and delay prioritized packets by an indefinite amount.

Can I somehow use HTTPS/2s / TCPs flow/congestion control for myself here? Or will I need to implement a basic flow/congestion control system on top of gRPC?

To be slightly more precise: I'd like to send as much data as possible without filling up any internal buffers, causing delays down the line.

Comment: I didn't know http/2 had that sort of thing. Cool. Is there a reference link for it?

Comment: At first look kestrel implementation seems to be internal, first thought; not sure if some middleware api can control that https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http2/FlowControl

Comment: @ziya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control  congestion control is handled by TCP, flow control by HTTP/2: https://medium.com/coderscorner/http-2-flow-control-77e54f7fd518 (or ietf https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540)

Comment: thanks @blenderfreaky .. Did you make any progress? I was wondering if you could write a middleware to make it work, but I don't know enough about middleware. Really interesting question btw +1

Comment: Not yet - currently it seems like it'd be easiest to simply implement my own. Another approach might be implementing a custom Stream/IAsyncEnumerable (so not with yield), which generates data when Read is called, assuming there are no internal buffers (since you'd probably just pass a BufferedStream yourself usually). ASP.NET should allow sending streams, so maybe something similar is possible here with protobuf-net

Answer (score 0):

Once data is written into the gRPC write buffer, there is no way to take it back unless you destroy the connection and reconnect.

Your requirements are:

1. make best use of network bandwidth
2. do not let large messages block causing **too much** latency for other priority messages.

A likely approach is to chunk the large message into smaller chunks (think about the similar concept as MTU in TCP), and write them to the gRPC streaming connection, interleaved with priority messages in between. On the receiver side, you have to maintain a buffer to re-assemble those chunks back into large messages. You may have to design some kind of metadata for those chunked messages so they can be put back together. gRPC stream connection guarantees delivery and order so the implementation should be relatively straightforward.

This way, you can still rely on the TCP for network congestion control, and gRPC/HTTP for flow control, but should get your priority messages through faster. Of course, the size of each chunk message needs to be tuned to best fit your scenario.